# HTML5 How to align a table to center inside a form?

Tags: css, html, alignment, text-align

I have a `<form>`, and inside that form, I have a `<table>`. I tried using `text-align: center` and `align-items:center` on that form, but the table inside it is still aligned to the left (while the table's child elements are aligned to the center inside that table). How can I align a table the the center, inside a form?

Comment: Did you try `margin: auto`? It works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/gdc9f65p/

Comment: Look at this: http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When u want to align a table in the center position of the parent, simply use:

**css:**

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

EXAMPLE:

**html:**

```
<form >
 <table>

 </table>
</form>
```

**css:**

```
form {
  width:80%; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: black;
}

table {
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 1;
   width:50%; 
   height: 50px; 
   background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvo7v7f9/